# Nginx 98: Address already in use - Failed to start A high performance web server issue

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, hhvm

My Server Working Good... Until Reboot, After Reboot Nginx not Running Good!

OS: Ubuntu server

nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)

HHVM Script Server

I Try many Methods But I can't Fix This:

### Configuration Has been Ok.

```
nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

---

```
Aug 06 16:05:48 HHVM systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit nginx.service has begun starting up.
Aug 06 16:05:48 HHVM nginx[1618]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 06 16:05:49 HHVM nginx[1618]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 06 16:05:49 HHVM nginx[1618]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 06 16:05:50 HHVM nginx[1618]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 06 16:05:50 HHVM nginx[1618]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 06 16:05:51 HHVM nginx[1618]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Aug 06 16:05:51 HHVM systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 06 16:05:51 HHVM systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit nginx.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Aug 06 16:05:51 HHVM systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 06 16:05:51 HHVM systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

NginX runnig and I see "404 File Not Found" on Web browser,that meaning hhvm not running .

How can i fix it?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/search?q=Nginx+98%3A+Address+already+in+use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to find `pid` of `nginx` so that you can kill it. To find `pid` just type

```
ps aux | grep nginx
```

Once you find the `pid`, you can kill that process like this.

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

But the easiest way is to just restart it by using following command:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

or

```
sudo service nginx stop
sudo service nginx start
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check which process is listening on port 80, and make sure that service is disabled in systemd. You can find the process with `netstat -lnp` command, looking for port 80 in the output.